# Python Pandas Dataframe check column of lists and return ID from another Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, list-comprehension, melt

I have a pandas dataframe `df1` which has an index, and a column of lists and looks like:

```
index   IDList
0   [1,3,5,7]
1   [2,4,5,8]
2   [6,8,9]
3   [1,2]
```

I have another pandas dataframe `df2` which has NewID as the index, and a column of lists which looks like this:

```
NewID   IDList
1       [3]
2       [4,5]
3       [1,7]
4       [2]
5       [9,3]
6       [8]
7       [6]
```

What I need to do is if any of the items in `df1.IDList` exist in `df2.IDList`, then return a list of the relevant `df2.NewID`.

So the returned `d1` dataframe would look like:

```
index   IDList      NewID
0       [1,3,5,7]   [3,1,2,3,5]
1       [2,4,5,8]   [4,2,2,6]
2       [6,8,9]     [7,6,5]
3       [1,2]       [3,4]
```

**EDIT:** Note that in `df2` there can be ID in *IDList* that occurs in multiple rows (see *ID* 3 from `df1.IDList` and where *ID* 3 shows up in `df2` rows 1 AND 5)

I was thinking some kind of `np.where` statement which incorporates '`any`' and a list comprehension?  but uncertain how to apply for each `IDList` in `df1` where it looks at the whole of `df2.IDList`.  Maybe some kind of `.stack()`?  or `.melt()`?  This would be easy in a spreadsheet with a vlookup of df2...

Help appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# expand and map ids from IDList to NewID
flat_ids = pd.DataFrame({
    "NewID": pd.np.repeat(df2.NewID, df2.IDList.str.len().tolist()),
    "IDList": [x for l in df2.IDList for x in l]
}).set_index("IDList").NewID

# extract ids from flat ids using loc
df1['NewID'] = df1['IDList'].map(lambda x: flat_ids.loc[x].tolist())
```

[image]

Comment: shoot, there may be duplicates in the IDList column from df2.  I'll edit

Comment: OK. I get it wrong. This should also work if there are duplicates in the *IDList* column.

Comment: Getting: TypeError: repeat() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Comment: Maybe you got some parenthesis unbalanced or which version of python and pandas are you using? on python 2.7.9 and pandas 0.19.2, it seems to work fine.

Comment: python 3.4.5, pandas 17.1

Comment: You might consider upgrade your pandas version, that's pretty old. Not necessarily the problem though.

Comment: It was the pandas version.  Thanks so much, great job on a challenging ?.  This works perfectly.